# Wordpress - tracking options

Tags: security, filesystem, wp-filesystem, privacy

I wanted to ask, how much is it possible to track users when using WP as a CMS. For example, can I see, when users go to certain directories like wp/files or open specific documents like wp/files/docs/ex.pdf?

BR,Mel

Comment: Your server logs will show a certain amount of this, though they wouldn't provide info on specific WP users' actions. You should search [the WordPress plugin directory](https://wordpress.org/plugins/) for something like `audit logging`.

Comment: thanks for your answer. So IP adresses cannot be logged for statitics for example (without a plugin)? Like how many people downloaded my file from a certain region?

Comment: Edit: Im sorry by users I mean the visitors. I know, that there are loggin for WP users. sorry

Comment: IP addresses do get logged in your web server access log - assuming the requests get that far. If you have a cache layer in front of your website your requests might not get to the server though, but hopefully you'll have logging from the cache somehow.

Comment: It might be simplest to look at something like Google Analytics though. Not sure if that works easily for downloads but it does a good job of general page views etc.

Comment: Thanks @Rup.  So the thing is that it is very easy for a user to find all my documents in .../files/ where the user sees all pdf's at one place and then can open them directly. So I think that Google Analytics does not work for that case. I am just wondering, if there is some "loggin" of IP's for visitors who visit .../files/ and access the documents directly.